# Facebook's og:image is not working on production site

Tags: django, facebook

I have the problem. There is two identical sites: production and test one.

I'm placing in `head`

```
<meta
    property="og:image"
    content="http://{{ site.domain }}{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.preview.image }}"
>
```

And that image showing on facebook share page https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php with test site's link, but now showing with prodiction's one. The sites are fully identical except servers. Production is placing in Hetzner dedicated server, test server on DigitalOcean VPS.

The problem disappears after debugging the link in facebook object debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Finvestcafe.ru%2Fblogs%2F05525565%2Fposts%2F38607. After debugging image shows excellent.

Any ideas? This problem makes me angry >_<

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will cache the shared site. After running debugger, it will refreshed it's cache

Comment: So what's the solution?